# Reactjs - transition one div on top of another with a slide-in slide-out animation

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a page with two divs. Each div takes up the whole screen so one div at the start is on top and visible while the other is not visible. When I click a button on the first div I want the second div to slide in and become visible on top of the first div. Then I want the second div to slide-out and show the first div again.

My problem is I don't know how to tie together the javascript and css. When I click the button and fire an event I am not sure how to start the animation.

**React**

```
const styles = {
  p1: "page1",
  p2: "page2",  
  slideIn: "slideIn",      
}


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

} 

  handleClick = () => {

    //Make Page 2 slide in and then slide out
    //Apply the class page2Visible to make page 2 visible

  };

  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;


    return (

<React.Fragment>
    <div className={`${styles.p1}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>Page 1</div>
    <div className={`${styles.p2} ${styles.slideIn}`}>Page 2</div>
  </React.Fragment>
    );

  }

}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

**CSS**

```
.App {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page1 {

  background-color: blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:8;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;  

}

.page2 {

  background-color: red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:8;
  top:0;
  left:0; 
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slideIn {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slideOut {
  animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
  0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}


.page2Visible {

  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: just add the class with the animation in your state, and use that for your react component's className. Then when you click the button, update your state so the class has the right name so that animation works. I'd put this as an answer but i'm too lazy to read all the code and not sure if this is what your issue is : )

Comment: here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/ax82s7hf/2/ if that helps let me know and I'll put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Initially, you have to maintain a state for the current active div. Each div has a button when clicked hide that particular div and make the other div active. In the example code which I've given below, I've given the div's height as 500px but you can provide the height as you required. Here I'm using **ease-in-out** transition property to carry out the slide up and slide down animations. You can test the code in https://jsfiddle.net/krishnauppili/okn4vbe0/5/

Here is the **React** code(App.js):

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeDiv: "div1",
    }
}

toggleDiv = () => {
    this.setState({
        activeDiv: this.state.activeDiv === "div1" ? "div2" : "div1",
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className={this.state.activeDiv === "div1" ? "div1 show" : "div1 hide"} id="div1">
                Div 1
                <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleDiv}> Hide div1</button>
            </div>
            <div className={this.state.activeDiv === "div2" ? "div2 show" : "div2 hide"} id="div2">
                Div 2
                <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleDiv}> Hide div2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Here is the **CSS** code(App.css):

```
.div1{
    background-color: black;
}
.div2{
    background-color: green;
}
.div1,.div2{
    color:white;
}
.div1.show,.div2.show{
    height:500px;
    transition:  all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div1.hide,.div2.hide{
    text-align: center;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple issues, first you have to store your classes for animations in your state and update your state when you click on the blue box. Also, your animations and keyframe identifiers are not spelled consistently:

you have the animation set to `animation: slide-in` whereas the keyframes identifier is 'slideIn` notice one is camelcase the other has a dash. I copied your code into jsfiddle and have to working: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/y6xsveL5/22/

also i changed the animation from a translatex to a left property, it's set to `left: -100px` and the animation sets it to `left: 0`

I updated the jsfiddle so page 2 slides in, waits 2 seconds, then slides out. I used the setState callback function and set a timeout of 2 seconds then set the class from slideIn to slideOut: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/y6xsveL5/29/

then after about 600 milliseconds, I reset the class back to it's original state of no extra sliding class. This way if you click again it will slide again

I'm not sure if the setState callbacks are the right solution, I think there's a way to customize the animation from css to make it do a slide in followed by a slide out.

If you want page 2 to slide out when clicked on, you can replicate the handle click method for page 1 and just change the class to slide out

actually I updated the code again because there's a problem, if you click the blue page while the sliding is happening it throws off the animation because it updates the class before the animation is complete, you need to keep track of if the sliding is taking place, you dont allow the click to do anything until all animation are done:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/y6xsveL5/35/

final code:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  sliding = false;
  state = {
    page2Class: "",     
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    if (this.sliding) return;
    this.sliding = true;
    this.setState({ page2Class: 'slideIn' }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ page2Class: 'in-view slideOut' }, () => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ page2Class: '' }, () => {
              this.sliding = false;
            });
          }, 600)
        });
      }, 2000)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { page2Class } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='page1' onClick={this.handleClick}>Page 1</div>
        <div className={`page2 ${page2Class}`}>Page 2</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

css

```
.App {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page1 {
  background-color: blue;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:8;
  top:0;
  left:0; 
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
}

.page2 {
  background-color: red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  z-index:8;
  top:0;
  left:-100%; 
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;  
}

.in-view {
  left: 0;
}

.slideIn {
  animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}

.slideOut {
  animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slideOut 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  100% { left: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
  100% { left: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOut {
  100% { left: 100%; }
}


.page2Visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```